# predominant vs predominate

Tags: american-english

What is the difference between "predominant" and "predominate" and how much do academic writers care? I am writing a paper for Grad school.

I am trying to say "majority" and my text editor, Word, is suggesting both predomina**nt**ly and predomina**te**ly.

Example:

```
    In this case of eLearning, which is predominantly online, ....
```

Comment: What's the difference between an adjective and a verb?

Comment: Please show evidence of your research, e.g. *what difference is there* between the dictionary definitions of the two words, and *why you are still unsure* after considering those definitions.

Comment: You may be interested in [this Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predominately%2Cpredominantly&year_start=1700&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpredominately%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpredominantly%3B%2Cc0) showing the relative year-by-year frequency of "predominately" (blue line) and "predominantly" (red line) over the period from 1700 to 2005 in publications tracked in the Google Books database the Google Books database. As you can see, their fortunes have changed considerably since the late 1800s.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between "predominant" and "predominate"

The difference is that "predominant" is an adjective, while "predominate" is a verb - at least according to my dictionary. However, some dictionaries list it also as an adjective - see below.

In any case:

> **[Predominately](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predominately)** means the same as predominantly.

---

**Added**:

> ***[Predominant vs. Predominate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predominate)***
>   *Predominant* and *predominate* are synonymous adjectives. *Predominant* is the older and much more common form. A number of handbooks and commentators hold *predominate* to be a mistake—a few
>   insisting that the word is only a verb. But they are wrong. As an
>   adjective *predominate* is somewhat more likely to turn up in
>   technical writing than in general writing. The adverbs *predominantly*
>   and *predominately* are a more even match in frequency than their base
>   adjectives are, although *predominantly* is still significantly more
>   common than *predominately*.

---

According to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predominately%2Cpredominantly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpredominately%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpredominantly%3B%2Cc0), "predominantly" is used much more often than  "predominately".

Answer (score 1):

Formally, they are exact synonyms, but unusual adjectives that end in `-ate` (*spatulate*, *prostrate*) to me always seem Latinate (heh-heh) and forced.  They [smell of the lamp](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smell_of_the_lamp).

Use *predominant*.

Comment: I upvoted because I agree with the advice for this particular word but adjectives ending in “-ate” are not that uncommon. *Immediate, intermediate, approximate, accurate...* Saying that “unusual” ones seem odd seems a bit tautological

Comment: @sumelic — sorry, did not meant to imply that `-ate` was itself unusual, just that  compared to other adjectival endings (`-y`, `-al`), it makes an unusual word _feel_ high-flown.